# CodePush react-native ios failed

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, code-push

I am trying to release the React-Native iOS application using Microsoft's Codepush on staging. For this I followed the given instructions on the website and was able to build the bundle file and release successfully on staging but I didn't see the updated changes on mobile which I released.

Firstly I installed the application on mobile using usb (Run on device).

After that I made some changes in my application and released on staging using codepush but when I restarted the app on mobile, it's not showing the changes.

[iOS Setup](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push#getting-started)

```
version: 1.0.0
react-native: 0.17.0
react-native-code-push: 1.5.3-beta

react-native bundle --platform ios --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output codepush.js --dev false 
code-push release AwesomeProject codepush.js 1.0.0
```

Can any one help please ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow steps that you posted look correct, so I'm not entirely sure what the issue could be without seeing the logs generated by the CodePush plugin when running your app. If you take a look at our [troubleshooting docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push#debugging--troubleshooting), it explains how to examine the logs, along with some common issues and workarounds.

One potential issue is that you're not calling "sync" within the componentDidMount of your root component, and therefore, the plugin thinks your update failed, and rolled it backed. To fix this you simply need to call "CodePush.notifyApplicationReady" in your root component's componentDidMount to notify the CodePush runtime that the update should be considered successful.